# getImageData returns 4 values for 1 pixel

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I am running the below code and everytime it fires it returns four values.

```
var imgd = ctx.getImageData(2, 2, 1,1);
var pix = imgd.data;
console.log(pix);
for (var i = 0; n = pix.length, i < n; i += 4) {
    if (pix[i] == 0) {
        alert(i);
    }
}
```

I am sending in the data for position x = 2 and y = 2. Width and height = 1 pixel each.

I expected the value returned to be a single value. Why does it return 4 values in the console when I click a blaxk part of the image?

It returns 0, 255, 255, 255

Comment: That looks a lot like RGBA values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **For each pixel in an ImageData object there's four pieces of information, the RGBA values:**
>   R - The color red (from 0-255)
>   G - The color green (from 0-255)
>   B - The color blue (from 0-255)
>   A - The alpha channel (from 0-255; 0 is transparent and 255 is fully visible)
>   The color/alpha information is held in an array, and is stored in the data property of the ImageData object.

**Source:** http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_getimagedata.asp

> **If you'd like to convert RGB to Hex values:** (`255,255,255` to `#ffffff`)

```
var imgd = ctx.getImageData(2, 2, 1,1);
var pix = imgd.data;
console.log(pix);
for (var i = 0; n = pix.length, i < n; i += 4) {
    var red = pix[i];
    var green = pix[i+1];
    var blue = pix[i+2];
    var alpha = pix[i+3];
    var color = rgb2hex(red,green,blue);
    console.log("color: "+color);
}
function rgb2hex(red, green, blue) {
    var rgb = blue | (green << 8) | (red << 16);
    return '#' + (0x1000000 + rgb).toString(16).slice(1)
}
```

**Example: [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/kinona/3/edit?js,output)**

Another good resource: [HTML5 Canvas Image Data Tutorial](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-get-image-data-tutorial/)

Comment: ... and the importance of r1+g1+b1+a1, r2+g2+b2+a2 format is that the data can be very, very quickly copied to the GPU (or display or another canvas). This format is what makes the canvas so wicked fast! :-)